# Explanation of the output of Java code - postIncrement operator

Tags: java

I am looking for the answer to the backend logic for the code.

```
int i=4;
System.out.println("Output"+ (i += i++));
System.out.println("Output Step 2"+ i);
```

The answer is 8 in both cases. Now for the first step the answer 8 is very natural as `i += i++` translates to `i = i + i++`;.

As `i++` is the post increment operator it should increase the value to 9 in step 2. What is the flaw in my understanding?

Comment: Steps: temp = i + i; i++; i = temp;

Comment: `As i++ is post increment operator it should increase the value to 9` No, because the sum gets done _before_ incrementing i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
int i=4;

int temp = i + i; // 8
i = i + 1;
i = temp;         // still 8

System.out.println("Output"+ i);        //8
System.out.println("Output Step 2"+ i); //8
```

Hence the result is `8` in both cases.

Comment: Your answer seems convincing but how did u arrive at this conclusion? Is there a precedence rule which is used in this case to evaluate the expression?

Comment: @SamDJava As you said, `i++` is the postfix increment operator. Which means that `i = i + 1` gets executed _after_ the other instructions on the line. That's why it first sums up and then increments i.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println("Output"+ (i += i++)); // sum will be 8, i=8
```

Then post operator of `i++` not take any effect because of the summation happen before that.

Make sure that `Java` passed by value.

Actually what happen?

when `int i=4` [image: 1]

When `System.out.println("Output"+ (i += i++));` [image: 2][image: 3][image: 4][image: 5]

when  `System.out.println("Output Step 2"+ i);` [image: 6]

You can try this with [Jeliot](http://cs.joensuu.fi/jeliot/)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the first i++ is erased by the assignation i += i++.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the "i += i++", exist value of the i variable is adding to the itself before increment it from 1. After adding the value then increase the value from 1. That is why System.out.println("Output"+ (i += i++)); is showing "Output 8" as the output.

Also if you use i++, that change is not affect to the original variable. That is why you get same result at the second output also.